# Data not showing in table view in JSON parsing in iOS

Tags: ios

I am doing JSON parsing, but my data is only shown in log and not in *Tableview*.

I am showing the main method of JSON parsing below. I would like to show the whole code but Stack Overflow doesn't allow me.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [_CenterTableview setHidden:NO];
    [_CenterTableview reloadData];

    NSString *str=@"http://www.vallesoft.com/vlcc_api/getservicenames.php?centrename=";
    NSURL * url=[NSURL URLWithString:str];
    NSURLRequest *req=[[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
    Connection1=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
    if (Connection1) {
        WebData1=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }

    // [self.CenterTableview reloadData];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSDictionary *json=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:WebData1 options:0 error:0];
    NSArray *city_info =[json objectForKey:@"city_info"];
    for(NSDictionary *dic in city_info)
    {
        NSArray *vlcc_service_name=[dic objectForKey:@"vlcc_service_name"];
        Centers=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:vlcc_service_name, nil];

        //This Nslog showing service name //
        NSLog(@"%@",vlcc_service_name);
    }
}
```

But in *Tableview*, it is not showing:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [Centers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that You have set the tableview delegate to self?

Comment: Could any one help??i am trying till morning..Please solve this issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `reload` the `tableview` once you get the `centers` array filled in `didFinishLoading`

```
///Your code......
Centers=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:vlcc_service_name, nil];
[_CenterTableview reloadData];
////Your code.....
```

Comment: Yes,This could help you. Try this out. You must have to reload the tableview whenever you update you data from web.

Comment: Actually main problem is that in enters no data  shown thats why it is not showing in table view.. Could you please tell me how i show data in enters..?

Comment: @chandra Please suggest me how i accept this answer on stack overflow??

Comment: Moreover, don't `init `the the array every time you are fetching the contents from the web-service. Initialize it in `viewDidLoad`.